# SwiftUI ListStyle on macOS

Tags: macos, list, background, swiftui, drag

On macOS, using SwiftUI, regarding List:

I need to modify the List's background color.

Using the view debugger I see that the List has a ListCoresScrollView inside, with an internal `_NSScrollViewContentBackgroundView` and a NSVisualEffectView. That view has a white background by default. I want to change that particular view (e.g. to become transparent) because it seems to be an internal view.

How can one modify the background view on a list (in macOS, *not* IOS)?

Btw, I tried using a SidebarListStyle(). That does offer the background I want, but... dragging behavior is different (undesired) in a SidebarListStyle. So an alternative solution to my question could be "how to modify dragging behavior on a SidebarListStyle to mimic the default dragging behavior"?

It has taken me many many hours, but I cannot come up with a proper solution. Can anybody provide a working solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update #2 (about 30 mins later)...

This works :)

```
extension NSTableView {
    open override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        super.viewDidMoveToWindow()

        // set the background color of every list
        backgroundColor = .clear
        enclosingScrollView?.drawsBackground = false
        enclosingScrollView?.backgroundColor = .clear
        enclosingScrollView?.autohidesScrollers = true
        enclosingScrollView?.verticalScroller = MyScroller()
    }
}

class MyScroller: NSScroller {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        self.drawKnob()
    }
}
```

#### Original answer

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but this is the *closest* I've managed to get. Still can't get the scrollbars (especially background) to be actually transparent. But, is closer than I was.

Add a swift file with this in your project (for now, I've just put it at the top of my ContentView.swift file).

```
extension NSTableView {
    open override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        super.viewDidMoveToWindow()

        // set the background color of every list
        backgroundColor = .clear
        headerView = nil
        enclosingScrollView?.drawsBackground = false
        enclosingScrollView?.backgroundColor = .clear
        enclosingScrollView?.hasHorizontalScroller = false
        enclosingScrollView?.autohidesScrollers = true
    }
}
```

From what I've read, this *should* work. But, it doesn't. I perhaps don't need all of those settings, but I'll keep adding until I can get it fully working.

HTH - please let me know if you've solved it fully.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer RichS. This actually works very well.

As a matter of fact, I found that it even seems to work without setting the backgroundcolor to .clear in viewDidMoveToWindow().

Answer (score 2):

I played with RichS's answer a bit more and found that the following suffices in my project:

```
extension NSTableView {
    open override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        super.viewDidMoveToWindow()

        backgroundColor = .clear
        enclosingScrollView?.drawsBackground = false
    }
}
```

YMMV, so please look at RichS's answer above if your scrolling does not work as expected.